# Variance of the slope when adding predictors

Tags: regression, variance

I came across an article with the following question:

> Consider a linear regression with one single covariate, y=β0+β1x1+ε
>   and the least-square estimates. The variance of the slope is Var[β1].
>   Do we decrease this variance if we add one variable, and consider
>   y=β0+β1x1+β2x2+ε ?

They showed, using simulation, that the answer is no as it depends on how correlated `x1` and `x2` are. Is there a way to prove this without simulation?

Comment: Take a look at the VIF ( variance inflation factor) it may be useful to understand the idea behind this result.

Comment: What happens to the variance when $x_2$ is a constant nonzero multiple of $x_1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the text book definition for the sampling variances of the OLS slope estimators for covariate j:

$$ Var(\hat{\beta_j}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{SST_j(1-R_j^2)} $$

where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the error term, SST is the total sample variation $\sum_{i=1}^n(X_{ij}-\bar{X}_j)$ in $X_j$ and $R_j^2$ is the R-squared from regressing $X_j$ on all other independent variables.

Coming back to your example it's easy to see that the variance of $\hat{\beta_1}$ increases when the correlation between $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ increases because a higher correlation implies a higher R-squared from regressing $X_{1}$ on $X_{2}$ (the denominator decreases).

Importantly, a larger variance of your estimator translates into larger confidence intervals and more uncertainty.